# How to Enable Package Log (Enterprise Manager)

Tags: sql-server

Any idea how to enable packages log (enterprise manager) in SQL2000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216427(SQL.80).aspx

It's a per-package setting, though.